# Creating an Application Launcher for GNOME 3 in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, launcher

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on my machine. I also have installed GNOME 3. I then installed the IDE IntelliJ without issue. However I installed it to a custom location and now the only way to run it is through the terminal via "./idea.sh". I would like to create an application launcher so I can launch IntelliJ via the applications list in the GNOME 3 windows manager. How would I do such a thing via the terminal, not through a 3rd part utility. I would also prefer to have the correct icon for the launcher, not a generic one. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

create a file called **intellij.desktop** in the directory **/usr/share/applications/**

my file looks like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
Comment=Free Java, Groovy, Scala and Android applications development
Exec=/path/to/your/bin/idea.sh
Path=/path/to/your/bin
Terminal=false
Icon=intellij-idea-ce
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE
```

for more details check this website, http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html

**edit**: mlissner (Thank you!) mentioned that intelliJ in particular implemented a feature to add that Icon/Launcher automatically. Just open IntelliJ IDE, go to *Tools* and click *Create Desktop Entry...*

Answer (score 59):

Run Intellij, then go to Tools > Create Desktop Entry.

Comment: It's perhaps the right answer for IntelliJ, however, and considering the title of the question, the chosen answer *is* the best as it is generic and it works.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 20 (Focal Fossa), create a launcher with `alacarte`.
The generated `.desktop` file is automatically placed in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Move it from there to `/usr/share/applications/` if it is to be accessible to all the computer's users.

Answer (score 0):

You can create launcher using following steps 
step 1) Install gnome-panel
    sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel

step 2) run gnome-desktop-item-edit
    gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications --create-new

step 3) fill the required values in widget